# How to send arguments in restorablePush? (flutter)

Tags: flutter

The [flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/restorablePush.html) on `restorablePush` says that "Any object that is serializable via the StandardMessageCodec can be passed as arguments. Often, a Map is used to pass key-value pairs." But I am struggling to do this, as the route builder needs to be static.

I've made a small example below that illustrates the problem - basically, I want to be able to pass `title` as an argument from `Screen1` to `Screen2` and display it in the `AppBar`. Not sure where and how to put the argument in.

```dart
class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen1> createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  String title = 'blah';

  static Route<void> _myRouteBuilder(BuildContext context, Object? arguments) {
    return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => const Screen2(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.restorablePush(context, _myRouteBuilder);
              // Put somewhere... arguments: {'appBarTitle': title}
            },
            child: const Text('Go to Screen 2')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen2> createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  String _string = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    _string = args['appBarTitle'] ?? 'error';
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(_string)),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the settings parameter to MaterialPageRoute so that ModalRoute receives the argument on screen 2.

```
class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen1> createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  String title = 'blah';

  static Route<void> _myRouteBuilder(BuildContext context, Object? arguments) {
    return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      settings: RouteSettings(name: '/screen2', arguments: arguments),
      builder: (BuildContext context) => const Screen2(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.restorablePush(context, _myRouteBuilder, arguments: {'appBarTitle': title});
              // Put somewhere... arguments: {'appBarTitle': title}
            },
            child: const Text('Go to Screen 2')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen2> createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  String _string = 'Test';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args =
    ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;
    if(args is Map){
      _string = args['appBarTitle'] ?? 'error';
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(_string)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you! One question: is the `name: '/screen2'` in the settings necessary?

Comment: `name` is not required.